# How to do unit testing using Jest and enzyme for these type of code segmentations?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I tried so hard to implement the unit testing using jest and enzyme to the below code, but i haven't idea about how to write the unit test correctly. Always i got the test result as 'failed'.

I really appreciate the little support you give me to figure it out and pass the unit testing.

I used context API to fetch data.
I need to unit test the exact path navigation in App.js,

code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/layout/Navbar";
import Index from "./components/layout/Index";
import Lyrics from "./components/tracks/Lyrics";

import { Provider } from "./context";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider>
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="container">
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
                <Route path="/lyrics/track/:id" component={Lyrics} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05YSE.png)

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to use useLocation or useHostory hooks on your unit test to read the pathname and make assertions? Maybe that is the way.